# windows phone emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-emulator

I am trying to run the windows phone 8.1 emulator on windows 8.1 pro through visual studio but after the emulator opens and it shows a "Windows Phone OS is starting" message, I get the following error

Windows phone emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running:
Something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch512MB....' failed to start.
'Emulator 8.1 .......' failed to start worker process: Server Execution failed (......)

The emulator did work before on the same system and same os. But, suddenly it has stopped working.

I have searched this problem on google and found out that this problem occurs when running windows 8.1 on a virtual machine. But I am not running my windows 8.1 on any VM.

I have tried reinstalling HyperV on my system and failed to solve the problem.

What could be the issue here?

I have also reinstalled my visual studio and windows phone 8.1 emulators. Still the problem persists!

Comment: Did you make sure, the `Hyper-V` is enabled?

Comment: Yes, Hyper-V was enabled from the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a number of stuff I found out that the problem was with Hyper-V and reinstalling it did  not help. So ultimately I resorted to reinstalling windows using the "Refresh your PC without affecting your files" option. Selecting this option does not require reinstalling any of the softwares installed on your PC. Reinstalling windows 8 sorted the problem with Hyper-V and now I can run the windows phone 8.1 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to start it in administration mode or try to start it in a Compatibility mode. This should fix your problem.

Comment: I am running it in administrator mode. But, still doesn't work. I am getting the same error message.