# Tried all options but still Windows Phone emulator is unable to start

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

```
    OS : Windows 8.1 Pro
    Visual Studio Community Edition 2013

    Hardware
    4 GB Ram
    Core i3


Hyper-V is enabled 
Checked SLAT support with this software https://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/downloads/get/501307 and it says my system support it.
```

The first error I got was 
[image]

I read this and made the registry changes 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2911380/en-us

restarted my system and tried running the emulator again also this time I got same error
[image]

after googling a while I tried this
[windows phone emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075490/windows-phone-emulator-is-unable-to-verify-that-the-virtual-machine-is-running)

reinstalled windows using the "Refresh your PC without affecting your files" option

and I'm still unable to run the emulator!

What should I do?
It's been 6 hours since I'm trying to fix this.Please help anyone.

Comment: This happens to me with a few Visual Studio instances and emulators, there simply is not enough free RAM in your system

Answer (score 0):

Close all programs(Including anti-virus). Free maximum RAM. 
Open Hyper-V manager and find the name of your virtual machine(emulator) created there. Copy the name of the emulator which you need to start. 
Now using cmd move to the path where xde.exe is present. 
In my PC it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0".
Now, pass the command

xde.exe -name NameOftheEmulator

If you dont find any virtual machines in hyper-v manager, keep the hyper-V manager open and try running any emulator using Visual Studio. It will create a virtual machine automatically there. 
Also in the hyper-v manager, you can edit the RAM s